# Windows 7 time synchronization does not work

Tags: windows-7, date-time, ntp

I have a strange behaviour when trying to connect to  time server on my freshly installed Win7 x64 SP1: First of all, normally you need to pass a UAC check if you want to enter a timeserver, this does not happen here, although UAC is generally working.

Next, what I noticed is that whatever time server I enter, even those that are working perfectly fine on other computers on my network, I get a connection timeout. When I quit the dialog where I can enter the timeserver, it says the clock has been successfully set, althoufgh the time is about 10 minutes wrong.

Why does that happen?

Answer (score 0):

> Next, what I noticed is that whatever time server I enter, even those that are working perfectly fine on other computers on my network, I get a connection timeout.

That's probably because you're just typing in the new Time Server and hitting "Update Now". This doesn't work because the new time server you typed in doesn't actually take effect until you hit OK to close the "Internet Time" dialog box.  So you're just repeatedly trying to update from the original, non-working time server (even though you typed in a new address).

Type in the address of the time server you know works, hit OK, then open the dialog back up and hit "Update Now".

> it says the clock has been successfully set, although the time is about 10 minutes wrong.

Assuming what I said above is correct, then my guess is that since you haven't actually sync'd to a time server successfully you time hasn't actually been updated (properly). Try another time server  and see if it's still out by 10 minutes.